# Dropdown menu with sub menu that is not in the frame

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have this dropdown with submenu that is going beyond its frame. I am already using bootstrap 4 I thought it is responsive but it's not. The window width of this is desktop 100%. Can you suggest some sample code that will position the arrow and the menu to the left if it's past the frame?

I censored some of the texts btw.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu show" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" id="testDiv1">
<li class=""><a name="TEST1" class="dropdown-item " href="#">TEST1</a></li>
<li class=""><a name="TEST2" class="dropdown-item " href="#">TEST2</a></li>
<li class=""><a name="TEST3" class="dropdown-item " href="#">TEST3</a></li>
<li class=""><a name="TEST4" class="dropdown-item " href="#">TEST5</a></li>
<li class=" show"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle " href="#">TEST6</a> 
    <ul class="dropdown-menu  show" id="testDiv"> 
        <li><a name="TEST_DATA1" class="dropdown-item" href="#">TEST_DATA1</a></li>
        <li><a name="TEST_DATA2" class="dropdown-item" href="#">TEST_DATA2</a></li>
        <li><a name="TEST_DATA3" class="dropdown-item" href="#">TEST_DATA3</a></li>
    </ul>  
</li>
```

Comment: As you can [see](https://ibb.co/35Kyjtk) Bootstrap 4 does not automatically change position. You should calculate width of window and decide when to switch it's position to [Drop Left](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#dropleft)

Comment: Hi, my problem is that the elements are not static. And the window size of this is 100%

Comment: but will do that, thanks btw